# Output Stream not behaving as expected

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8

I was solving a question on codeforces and by a particular method one of the output stream didn't give its output.I was expecting the `System.out.println(c)`(this snippet prints the number of lines that follow) snippet also to give its output which it did till 26 test cases but on the 27th test case it failed to print its output.Although due to some modifications in my old code I was able to get the correct answer but I want to know why the previous code failed to print its output. Here is the relevant part of the former code

```
    int c=0;
    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : HM2.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue()!=-1) {
            ++c;
            int root=DS.root(entry.getValue());
            String rootString=getKeyByValue(HM,root);
            out.println(rootString+" "+entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(c);
    out.close();
```

And then I made some changes to the above code to get all test cases passed. Here is it:

```
    String outp="";
    int c=0;
    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : HM2.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue()!=-1) {
            ++c;
            int root=DS.root(entry.getValue());
            String rootString=getKeyByValue(HM,root);
            outp+=(rootString+" "+entry.getKey()+"\n");
        }
    }
    out.println(c);
    out.println(outp);
    out.close();
```

If you want to see full codes of both :here is it where you can see the test cases also : [Working Code](https://codeforces.com/contest/501/submission/58111831) [Failed Code](https://codeforces.com/contest/501/submission/58112854)
Expected output:
[image]
Ouput that is given:
[image]

Comment: What was the expected and the observed output?

Comment: @AshvinSharma In the 27th test case the number of lines which should follow was not printed while in the working code number of lines i.e 945 was printed before starting anything.You can see by going at the end of webpage in the two links shared

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking about. I have no idea what this code is supposed to do, what it does and what doesn't work. You shouldn't expect us to visit some outside websited to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure your PrintWriter works? I cannot write anything on it
**EDIT** - you need to `flush` your writer to make it work.

Comment: @Amongalen ,the rest of the part of the code is part of a problem solving problem on codeforces ,so I didn't care to share the whole code instead I shared only that part of the code upon changing which I got the correct answer. In short on one type of input the System.out.println(c); didn't give its output ,and i don't know why

Comment: @AshvinSharma out.close() does the same thing

Comment: @fuzious not really. `flush` and `close` are two different functions, although `close` does what you want, it then closes the stream permanently. While `flush` only clears the buffer after printing it on the output stream

Comment: Why would you print `c` after the loop execution btw? you want in the beginning no?

Comment: @AshvinSharma ,because the tester's code needs to know how many lines are being entered

Comment: in the beginning though, not in the end.

Comment: This really needs to be narrowed down to a [mcve] that focuses exclusively on this issue and gets rid of the surrounding context and that's fully included in the question. Although the issue here is probably just that the buffer size is not infinite, so flushing will presumably happen regardless at some point. You really shouldn't be using flushing to control the order in which things get written.

Comment: @Dukeling ,so do you mean to say that since the printwriter output stream might have overflowed during the execution so it flushed it's output before the System.out.println() snippet

Comment: @fuzious Yes, that seems likely. That would also explain why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.